# Python keep class in memory

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I'm fairly new to python so please correct me if my question does not make sens.

I am writing a small script, which should check some data and log those that failed. To have a better overview I am maintaining two files. One with my main function and the other with the other functions.

To log my failed data I have this class:

```
 class OutputLog():
  def __init__(self):
    self.errorLog = []

  def log(self, item: str):    #write data to errorLog if called
    self.errorLog.append(item)
    self.errorLog.append('\n')

  def write(self):             #return errorLog
    return self.errorLog
```

In my check function I call `OutputLog.log()` like this:

```
####### Check Data ########
class Check:
  def __init__(self, sortedData):
    self.sortedData = sortedData

## Check if name got spaces and log them
  def nameSpace(self):
    out = OutputLog()
    for column in self.sortedData:
      item = column[0]
      if ' ' in item:
        out.log(item)      #Call Output log
      else:
        continue
```

In my main function, which is in the other .py file (don't really know if this makes a huge difference) I want to get the error log like this:

```
import my_functions

def main():
  out = my_functions.OutputLog()
  c = my_functions.Check()
  c.nameSpace()
  print(out.write())
```

But like this my error log is still empty.
Is there a way how I can only have one instance of the OutputLog class or do I need to make the errorLog variable public?

If anyone knows a better way to do this I would love to hear your recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `out` variables are in different namespaces, and thus does not refer to each other. What you can do though, is change the `errorLog` variable to be a class-attribute instead of an instance-attribute.

```
class OutputLog:
    errorLog = []

    # Creates a classmethod that can be called without a create instance.
    @classmethod
    def log(self, item: str): 
        OutputLog.errorLog.append(item)

    # Creates a classmethod that can be called without a create instance.
    @classmethod
    def write(self):
        return OutputLog.errorLog

class Check:
    def __init__(self, sortedData):
        self.sortedData = sortedData

    def nameSpace(self):
        for column in self.sortedData:
            item = column[0]
            if ' ' in item:
                OutputLog.log(item)  # Calling the class-method directly, not an instance
            else:
                continue
```

You didn't provide any data to test the `Check` class, so I created my own data:

```
import my_functions

def main():
    c = my_functions.Check([" " for i in range(10)])
    c.nameSpace()
    print(my_functions.OutputLog.write()) # Output: [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']

main()
```

What I've done here is change the references from your `out` instances of `OutputLog` into the class itself, and changed the `methods` to be `classmethods` so that you can call them freely.

---

As a side-note, you should follow [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) and use 4-spaced indentation in your code to create better readability and standardized code so that it's easier to collaborate with others in the future.